# Draw one feature and deactive draw interaction

Tags: openlayers-3

I’m working on a draw tool using draw interaction. When the user has finished drawing one object the draw interaction should be deactivated. I tried with setActive(false) in the ‘drawend’ event. But then it seems the draw interaction is canceled prematurely. For example the zoom interaction get triggered if the drawing is finished with double click.
My workaround was to set a timeout, like this:

```
drawTool = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: drawOverlay.getFeatures(),
    type: activeTool,
    style: style
});
drawTool.on('drawend', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){drawTool.setActive(false);},100);
});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is already outlined as an [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3610/) in ol3. Time delay seems to be the current workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
source.on('addfeature', function(evt){
    drawTool.setActive(false);
});
```

If you need to check if the added feature is from draw interaction then you need some more code. Let me know if this is your case.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same result as drawend. If the drawing is finished with double click then zoom interaction is triggered.

Comment: Do you want to disable double click?

Comment: I want to keep double click disabled for zoom when finishing drawing. When feature is added, double click for zoom should be activated but not triggered. I also intend to add a click listener for other interaction after (but not triggered) feature is addded. Thus the time delay.